# How to display Firebase data with multi-level key on HTML table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble with displaying data from a Firebase database with a multi-level key to an HTML table, using Angular.

I have data like this:

[image: This is my data]
[image: Result after rendering with <code>ng-repeat</code>]

I have tried to display with `ng-view`, the result like this:

My Controller:

```
.controller('SalesCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {

    console.log('Sales Controller loaded..');
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("pelanggan/sales01");

    var list = $firebaseObject(ref);

    list.$loaded().then(function() {
        $scope.list = [];
        angular.forEach(list, function(value,key){
            $scope.list.push({ id: key, data: value})
        });
    });
```

I have tried to render it with different methods like `ng-repeat` and `ng-repeat-start.`  I am confused as to why I get JSON format on my table.

I would like to display the data with format like above:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| alamat         | email        | identitas      | layanan  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| jl.prapanca... | xx@email.com | 12345          | xxxxxxxx |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Since the problem appears to be in your view, could you provide the part of your view that you're using to try to render this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the problem is that `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` are the wrong tools for the situation.  Based on my day-to-day work, I've found that if you're operating on an HTML table, a more basic `ng-repeat` setup is preferable.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>alamat</td>
      <td>email</td>
      <td>identitas</td>
      <td>layanan</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list">
      <td>{{item.alamat}}</td>
      <td>{{item.email}}</td>
      <td>{{item.identitas}}</td>
      <td>{{item.layanan}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The reason I say this, is that if you look at [the Angular documentation for ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), you'll find that, while the special `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` points can be used for special purposes in tables, they're more helpful for `<div>s`.

Since you're getting the data back as JSON anyhow, you can simply reference the relevant properties and put them in the right place by hand.

If you're trying for an 'elegant' setup where you're dynamically rendering the table, I'm not sure you'll be able to pull that off very easily.  I don't know the requirements of what you're working on, though.  Thus, I suggest the easiest path you can take, which is a plain `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I just have solved my problem similar with what just you said, I will show it in comment above

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I just have solved it with the following.

In my Controller I change to:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("pelanggan").child("sales01");
$scope.sales = $firebaseArray(ref); 
var data = $firebaseArray(ref); 
$scope.info = $scope.sales 
console.log("info: "+data.length);
```

And in my view:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="SalesCtrl">
<!-- <div class="row" ng-controller="singlePelangganController"> -->

<div class="col-md-5" ng-show="addSalesFormShow">
    <h3>Add Sales</h3>
    <form ng-submit="addSales()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Alamat</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="alamat" placeholder="Alamat" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Identitas</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="identitas" placeholder="Identitas" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>lo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="lo" placeholder="lo" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>lt</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="lt" placeholder="lt" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nama</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="nama" placeholder="Nama" required="">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      <!-- <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-default" onclick='resetForm()'>Cancel</button> -->
    </form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-5" ng-show="editSalesFormShow">
    <h3>Edit Sales</h3>
    <form ng-submit="editSales()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Alamat</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="alamat" placeholder="Alamat" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>lo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="lo" placeholder="lo" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>lt</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="lt" placeholder="lt" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nama</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="nama" placeholder="Nama" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>No Handphone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="phone" placeholder="Phone" required="">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-7">
    <h3>Sales</h3>

    <table class="table table-striped hoverTable" data-ng-controller="SalesCtrl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Alamat</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Identitas</th>
                <th>lo</th>
                <th>lt</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>   
        </thead>
        <tbody data-ng-repeat="sales in sales">
             <tr>
                <td>{{sales.alamat}}</td>
                <td>{{sales.email}}</td>
                <td>{{sales.identitas}}</td>
                <td>{{sales.lo}}</td>
                <td>{{sales.lt}}</td>
                <td>{{sales.nama}}</td>
                <td>{{sales.noHP}}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="showEditSalesForm(sales)">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeSales(sales)">Delete</a></td>
             </tr>





        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</div>
```